# Дрожание во время анимации

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Рисую текстуру на `GL_QUAD`, запускаю анимацию движения. При движении текстуры двигается рывками. Отрисовка идет в отдельном потоке, стоит sleep 1 мсек, время между кадрами 0 - 15 мсек.

Похоже это частая проблема при программировании 3д графики. Падение фрэймрейта на гпу, но пока непонятно ничего.

Как этого избежить?

*Проверялось на Delphi, Qt, OpenFrameworks.*

Comment: в программировании графики есть такое понятие как двойная буферизация.. почитайте про нее и вы найдете решение своей проблемы..

Comment: Двойная буферизация не спасает. Судя по различным форумам проблем с синхронизацией по таймеру.
http://sim0nsays.livejournal.com/11847.html - вот как я понял решение, но я пока нее понимаю его(.

Answer (score 4):

В таких случаях обычно организуют `Draw/Update` цикл. Приведу пример:

```
// в начале приложения при инициализации:
lastUpdateTime = GetCurrentTime();

// ...

// код регулярно вызываемого метода
// (например, цикл обработки сообщений)
void DoWork()
{
    now = GetCurrentTime();
    while (lastUpdateTime + updateStep <= now)
    {
        Update();
        lastUpdateTime += updateStep;
    }

    Draw();
}
```

где `updateStep` это время, отведённое на шаг обновления логики; обычно равно `1000 / FramePerSecond`, если измерять его в миллисекундах.

В методе `Update()` выполняем обновление состояния (в данном случае - анимации движения), а в методе `Draw()` производим рисование сцены.

Организовать подобный метод, думаю, не составит труда.

Answer (score 2):

Были проблемы с таймером, частично решил. Таймер системный глючит, необходимо усреднять по времени, брать 10 кадров последних и считать среднее за это время. На половине компью.теров это помогло, на другой нет(.

Comment: "Это не баг, это фича!". Системный таймер имеет низкую точность для графики, около 16мс. Правильный ответ AlexeyM дал.

Answer (score 2):

Если ОС - windows, то:
  если вы указали параметром функции sleep() некоторое число (в данном случае 1 мсек), то поток будет "спать" от 1 до <любого*количества*мсек>, как решит диспетчер потоков. Если же нужно максимально приблизиться к времени "сна" (sleep()), то можно попробывать следующее:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
timeBeginPeriod( 1 ); // в мсек
...
//ваш код
...
timeEndPeriod( 1 );

//В файл проекта подключить либу
LIBS += -lwinmm
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему можно решить умножая все расчеты на n\кол-во кадров за t сек..

Где эксперементально подобрать n и t.

примерно так n= среднее кол-во кадров(на машине на которой было написано по)
T = от 0.1 сек. до 1 сек.